# API Design - Would it be best to run a shared api for customers and our web app or split it into 2 apis, private and public?

Tags: api, split, private, shared, public

Just in the design process at the minute but would like some advice from people who have deployed a similar solution and to share the experiences they have had.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest splitting it into two separate APIs, one public and one private. You have a lot more flexibility to make changes when your users are all internal vs. external. In addition, internal users typically need/expect more change in the system. The security considerations are also very different for internal vs. external APIs.

You can mitigate DRY issues by having the internal API call the external API where appropriate.